# jquery on iphone breaks when native app interupts safari?

Tags: jquery, iphone

When I launch the mail app from a mailto: link from a page in mobile safari on iphone os 3.1.1 (an ipod touch), everything works nicely.  When the mail is sent or cancelled, safari runs again, but all jquery functionality is gone.  I'm using jquery v1.3.2.  Ordinary inline javascript still runs.  Has anyone else noticed this and found a work-around?

Comment: Does this only happen in 3.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can user the jquery mobile http://jquerymobile.com/.
It's beta buts until now work fine with me, and have a lot of support.

You can view here http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ the list of compatible platforms

Best Regards.

Comment: While jQuery Mobile can, certainly, *be used* it would be interesting to know whether using it *solves the problem?*

Comment: I sad jquery mobile because it was developer exclusive for mobile, and dont have that type of error. Maybe can be another, because it's alpha.